# Custom Sign up form doesnt work -Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, wordpress-theming

My custom sign up form works perfectly on wordpress but when I modified it and include to modal it doesnt work.

below form works perfecktly:

```
 <?php


            global $wpdb;

            if ($_POST) {

                $username = $wpdb->escape($_POST['txtUsername']);
                $email = $wpdb->escape($_POST['txtEmail']);
                $password = $wpdb->escape($_POST['txtPassword']);
                $ConfPassword = $wpdb->escape($_POST['txtConfirmPassword']);

                $error = array();
                if (strpos($username, ' ')!==FALSE) {
                    $error['username_space'] = "Username has Space";
                }
                if(empty($username)) {
                    $error['username_empty'] = "Needed Username must";
                }
                if(username_exists($username)) {
                    $error['username_exists'] = "Username already exists";
                }
                if(!is_email($email)) {
                    $error['email_valid'] = "Email has no valid value";
                }
                if(email_exists($email)) {
                    $error['email_existence'] = "Email already exists";
                }
                if (strcmp($password, $ConfPassword) !==0) {
                    $error['password'] = "Password didn't match";
                }
                if (count($error) == 0) {
                    wp_create_user($username,$password,$email);
                    echo "User created successfully";
                    exit();
                }
                else print_r($error);
            }

            ?>

            <form method="post">

                <p>
                    <label for="txtUsername">Enter Username</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="txtUsername" name="txtUsername" placeholder="Username"/>
                </div>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label for="txtEmail">Enter Email</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="email" id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" placeholder="Email"/>
                </div>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label for="txtPassword">Enter Password</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="password" id="txtPassword" name="txtPassword" placeholder="Password"/>
                </div>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label>Enter Confirm Password</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="password" id="txtConfirmPassword" name="txtConfirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
                </div>
                </p>
                <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit"/>
            </form>
```

---

but this form doesnt work.It doesnt save user or notice any error even by php after delete alert.

> How can I solve it? What is the problem? Can you say me the solution?
>   I hope you will solve.Thank you for your solutions.

I call it like it:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" data-whatever="@mdo"><i class="fa fa-edit text-thm2"></i> Sign Up</a>
                                            <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                                                <?php get_template_part( 'include/sign-up' ); ?>

                                            </div>
```

here is sign-up.php:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

if ($_POST) {

    $username = $wpdb->escape($_POST['txtUsername']);
    $email = $wpdb->escape($_POST['txtEmail']);
    $password = $wpdb->escape($_POST['txtPassword']);
    $ConfPassword = $wpdb->escape($_POST['txtConfirmPassword']);

    $error = array();
    if (strpos($username, ' ')!==FALSE) {
        // $error['username_space'] = "Username has Space";
        ?>
<script>
    alert("Username has Space");
</script>
<?php
    }
    if(empty($username)) {
         $error['username_empty'] = "Needed Username must";
        ?>
        <script>
            alert("Username has Space");
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    if(username_exists($username)) {
         $error['username_exists'] = "Username already exists";
        ?>
        <script>
            alert("Username has Space");
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    if(!is_email($email)) {
         $error['email_valid'] = "Email has no valid value";
        ?>
        <script>
            alert("Username has Space");
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    if(email_exists($email)) {
         $error['email_existence'] = "Email already exists";
        ?>
        <script>
            alert("Username has Space");
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    if (strcmp($password, $ConfPassword) !==0) {
         $error['password'] = "Password didn't match";
        ?>
        <script>
            alert("Username has Space");
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    if (count($error) == 0) {
        wp_create_user($username,$password,$email);
         echo "User created successfully";
        ?>
        <script>
            alert("Username has Space");
        </script>
        <?php
        exit();
    }
    else {
        print_r($error);
        ?>
        <script>
            alert("Username has Space");
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}

?>
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="exampleModalLabel">Register</h4>
            <p class="text-center">Sign in and choose your service to have access to all our service.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <form class="ulockd-reg-form text-center row">
                        <h3> <span class="flaticon-house-key"></span> Register</h3>
                        <p>Join our community today:</p>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputNamexa" placeholder="Username" name="txtUsername">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmailx" placeholder="Email" name="txtEmail">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="txtPassword">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Repeat password" name="txtConfirmPassword">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group text-center">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default ulockd-btn-thm2" name="btnSubmit">Sign Me Up</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block color-white">Facebook</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
                            <a href="#">OR</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block color-white">Google</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- modal footer start here-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, one of form works, another from doesnt work.I call not-worked form and I share its code.I dont know what is the difference between these code so I couldnt solve the problem but in fact, yes, they are different

Comment: sing-up.php is different from first code which is top of question.Please, more focus

Comment: The second one has form inputs, but no `<form>` tag. Is there other code you haven't shown that has a handler for the `click` event on the "Sign Me Up" button?

Comment: @GregSchmidt you are right.After add form tag, it works now.But I have a different problem now.Sing up form is in modal so after click button, page doesnt load completly.I want to re-load only modal after click button -not all page.How can I do it?

Comment: @GregSchmidt you can chech yourself what I say above comment via this link:
http://www.hekim.deniz-tasarim.site/2020/04/22/denemenin1/
click sign up button, a form modal will appear.Fill the form correctly and click button.You will see what I mean

Comment: If you don't want the page to reload on submit, you're going to need to add a JavaScript click handler, Ajax form submission, and handle the response. Lots of tutorials out there about how to do these parts, hopefully this gives you enough key words to search them out.